# db.SaveChanges(); Not Committing changes in database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So i am a student learning Web API. I have developed a basic Web Api and when i use post method it gives me 500 iternal server error. The get methods are working fine. During debugging its hitting  db.SaveChanges(); but returns a 500 error while hitting              HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user); I am using mysql database with mysql connector 6.7.4.

STACKOVERFLOW is not lettting me post image, so here is the pic of my debug screen : http://i44.tinypic.com/25tyy3m.png

I am using fidler to send post request :

**Response Header**: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

**Request Header**: User-Agent: Fiddler Host: localhost:45379 Content-Type: application/jsonContent-Length: 41 Content-Length: 41

**Request Body**: {"iduser":"44444888","username":"oooooo"}

**Its my code for POST Method:**

```
        // POST api/User
       public HttpResponseMessage Postuser(user user)
       {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                 db.users.Add(user);
                 db.SaveChanges();

                 HttpResponseMessage response =R                           equest.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, user);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = user.iduser }));
                 return response;
          }
          else
          {
                 return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
          }
}
```

Comment: Wrap the `db.SaveChanges();` in a try block, and then catch the exception.  Put a breakpoint within the catch and see what the exception says.

Comment: Did this , it says -  $exception {"Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details."} System.Exception {System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException}

Comment: So it looks like user has some invalid entries.  Check the values of all the fields at runtime and make sure they make sense.  Examples: strings where ints should be, strings with a length longer than allowed in the DB.